# I installed Robo 3T on my mac but I am unable to connect to Mongodb Server

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am receiving the below error when trying to connect to remote Mongodb Server using Robo 3T on my MacOS. Anyone have solutions to get rid of the mongod.lock as I can't find it in the path as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems like you have not started mongodb in your system. First run your mongodb using following command in your system terminal and try connecting with Robo3T:

`mongod`

If you have not installed mongodb yet then first go through steps mentioned in below documentation, then start mongodb from terminal and then try connecting.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/